# PHP Static variable to store an array of functions

Tags: php, arrays, function, static

I am trying to store all the attribute predicates within a static array in PHP:

```
public static $attributeValidation = [
    "attribute1" => function ($value) {
        return is_bool($value);
    },"attribute2" => function ($value) {
        return is_int($value);
    },
];
```

I am getting this following error:

```
expression is not allowed as default field value.
```

The goal is to simplify attribute validation by using

```
$attributeValidation["attribute"]($someValue);
```

Is there a way to accomplish this without using a local/private variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to accomplish this without using a local/private variables

Yes. Simply create static method which would return the array you need:

```
public static function getAttributeValidation(): array
{
   return [
       // populate your array as you like
       ...
   ];
}
```

and then in your code instead of `SomeClass::$attributeValidation` you will do `SomeClass::getAttributeValidation()` to get that array.